How can I make Hibernate schedule insertions in the correct order with two Many-to-one relationships?
In my code, I have (don't worry about business logic, it's an example) Agreggate School:
class Document {
  
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.All)
  private List<Field> Field;


  @OneToMany
  private List<Rule> Rule;

  //getters and setters omitted by brevity

}

class Rule {

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.Lazy)
  @JoinColumn("field_origin_id", referencedColumnName="id")
  private Field fieldOrigin;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.Lazy)
  @JoinColumn("field_target_id", referencedColumnName="id")
  private Field fieldTarget;

  private Integer operator;
  private Integer agregator;

   //getters and setters omitted by brevity
} 

 class Field {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "fieldOrigin", cascade = CascadeType.All)
    private List<Rule> rulesThatHaveThisAsOrigin;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "fieldTarget", cascade = CascadeType.All)
    private List<Rule> rulesThatHaveThisAsTarget;


   // getter setters

   public void addRuleThatHasOriginHere(Rule rule) {
      rulesThatHaveThisAsOrigin.add(rule);
      rule.setOrigin(this);
   }


   public void addRuleThatHasTargetHere(Rule rule) {
      rulesThatHaveThisAsTarget.add(rule);
      rule.setTarget(this);
   }

} 

 
 

when I make something like

Document doc = new Document();
Field f1 = new Field();
Field f2 = new Field();
Rule r1 = new Rule();
f1.addRuleThatHasOriginHere(r1);
f2.addRuleThatHasTargetHere(r1);

Hibernate throws a JpaObjectNotFoundException for f2 or f1 because cascade Doc -> f1 -> r1 and f2 or f1 is not saved yet.
How can I control this? In my mind Hibernate should be smart enough to do in the right order, but I think something is wrong with my annotations.
Solve it, understand error.
